# Wifi not working on brand new HP laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, laptop, hp

I just installed Ubuntu 16.-04 on a brand new HP laptop, apparently with an Intel WiFi interface (WiFi/Bluetooth combined).

Unfortunately I cannot see anything about the WiFi adapter and WiFi does not work at all. Everything else, including Ethernet works fine.

Can anyone help me with that? I already tried many different approaches from this website, but so far no luck.

`wireless-info` script output:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Jul 2017 17:21 CEST +0200

Booted last: 28 Jul 2017 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-87-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 18 12:55:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:832c]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c9b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.49  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e9f2:288:9447:cb22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21940052 (21.9 MB)  TX bytes:1335607 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:51660 (51.6 KB)  TX bytes:51660 (51.6 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       792     1  0 16:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eno1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Kabelnetzwerkverbindung 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5ef3eb9e-b4ee-381a-ae4d-938f92111234
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5ef3eb9e-b4ee-381a-ae4d-938f92111234 | Kabelnetzwerkverbindung 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.49/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        vendor_unknown_3561 = 4:6:30:30:31:33:43:38:5:d:36:34:36:30:31:54:30:30:37:31:34:33:33:6:6:53:54:36:38:34:30
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       host_name = courtepin
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       expiry = 1501340274
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.49
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e9f2:288:9447:cb22/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist acer-wmi

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   23.419826] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   23.535847] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   23.535997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   27.216411] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link up
[   27.216440] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[  266.326852] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link down
[  281.844552] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link up
[  290.024828] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link down
[  312.694856] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: link up

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 7):

You have the 4.4 kernel. It doesn't support this Intel adapter. You probably installed Ubuntu from the original 16.04 ISO.

If you have a wired internet connection (it looks like you have updated your system), then install the [HWE kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

and reboot.

The wireless adapter should work.

Another option is to download and install the 16.04.2 "point" release (or a newer). It supports this adapter out of the box.

Comment: Wow, the HWE kernel worked like a charme! Thank you SO much. I spent hours to search for a solution.
May I ask what this HWE kernel is all about? I never heard about it.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type in:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

And reboot!

If the problem is still not solved, then try changing it to `ant_sel=2`.